# Not able to create bashrc in OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I am not able to create `.bashrc` file in the home directory. When I try to use `touch` I get:

```
touch: .bashrc: No such file or directory
```

When I type `vim .bashrc` in the home directory, and try to save using `:w`, it says

```
E166: Can't open linked file for writing
```

---

Edit:

Output of `ls -l .bash*`

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ankitsultana  staff    34 Oct 30  2014 .bash -> /Users/ankitsultana/.dotfiles/bash
-rw-------  1 ankitsultana  staff  7069 Nov 26 01:04 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 ankitsultana  staff  2633 Nov 26 13:51 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 ankitsultana  staff   167 Sep 21  2014 .bash_profile-anaconda.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 ankitsultana  staff  1791 Jun 30  2015 .bash_profile.pysave
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ankitsultana  staff    36 Oct 30  2014 .bashrc -> /Users/ankitsultana/.dotfiles/bashrc
```

Comment: Sounds like .bashrc is a symlink that points to a file you don't own/have permissions to modify. What does `ls -la ~` display?

Comment: Can you do `ls -l .bash*` and see the result?

Comment: I did `ls -l .bash*`, that returned `/Users/myname/.dotfiles/bashrc`. I have no clue why that exists there. It also showed `/Users/myname/.dotfiles/bash`. There's also these `.bash-history .bash_profile .bash_profile-anaconda.bak .bash_profile.pysave`

Comment: Can you put the entire output into the question? It will be easier to read.

Comment: Update: I can't `cd ~/.dotfiles`.

Comment: So it's a dangling symlink.  `rm .bashrc` and proceed as normal.